# All linux commands no working after try install python3.7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, checkinstall

I have big, weird problem. I have server on Hetzner with Ubuntu 20.

I tried install python3.7.2 with this instruction:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.2/Python-3.7.2.tgz 
Where version can be specific, the above FTP location contains lots of versions.
tar -xvf Python-<version>.tgz 
cd Python-<version>  
./configure 
make 
sudo checkinstall
```

Until 'make' command everything was fine, but after 'sudo checkinstall' I get a error:

```
File "/home/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
make: *** [Makefile:1130: install] Error 1

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup.../usr/bin/checkinstall: line 95: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory


/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 102: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 319: /usr/bin/rm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 320: /usr/bin/rm: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 95: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory


/usr/bin/checkinstall: line 95: /usr/bin/gettext: No such file or directory
```

And now in this moment all linux commands not working, ls, ps, python etc...

```
-bash: /usr/bin/su: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
-bash: /usr/bin/ps: No such file or directory
```

I reboot server manually, but it's not working. Anybody have a idea what's now? I never used 'make' and 'checkinstall' commands and now I'm stuck

Comment: Does ldd /usr/bin/ls do anything?

Comment: I think it is the same problem, with the same solution, as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/909859 https://github.com/giuliomoro/checkinstall/issues/4